# Disable Firefox's APZ

Tags: javascript, firefox

does anybody know if there opportunity to disable Firefox Async Pan/Zoom (also called APZ) with JS?
I know that there is browser flag `layers.async-pan-zoom.enabled` which is set to `true` by default. Unfortunately I have no permission to change it so that's why I'm asking how to disable it via JS. I also can't use CSS rule `position: sticky;`.

Thanks.